# Activating submit element in a form at a specified time

Tags: web-browser, automation

Lets say i want to submit a question to here sharply at 01:42:36:586 with the orange "post your question" button.
How do i do this ? Do i need to know javascript and how to interact with apis ? Or is there a program that you can synchronize with windows's time that will simply click on a coordinate at the time set , or an addon that lets you submit html commands with a time setting ?

e.g imacros or murgee auto mouse click with the option of specfying execute time instead of the interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that between the fact that most desktop OSs are not real time and that all web transactions have a variable latency you are unlikely to be able to reach a millisecond accuracy of the timing of your post. That said both of the following can be setup to try to perform actions at a specific time:

### Option 1.

The [python](http://python.org) [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library can pretend to be a browser and take any actions that you need. Note that you will have to look into the structure of the form to get this to work.

### Option 2.

The [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) test suit, (also python based), can find and click on buttons as well as filling in the form, even if they move because it recognises items on the screen. This option will not require you to get into the structure of the form.

Both of the above options are free and cross platform.